Bing is not indexing my site
This is ridiculous, It's been since 2021 and the problem persists, the last time i contacted them in 2021 they responded with this pre written template twice:
"We are not able to provide specifics for these types of issues because the relevant teams do not share reports with us. We recommend that you review our Webmaster Guidelines, especially the section Things to Avoid, and thoroughly check your site for any deliberately or accidentally employed SEO techniques that may have adversely affected your standing in Bing and Bing-powered search results. We will not be able to add your site to the index while Bingbot is finding it in violation of Webmaster Guidelines. We have no control over this process, and you will need to make quality changes to your site and wait for the Bingbot's automated crawling process to agree that the site passes the webmaster standards before it can be served.
"
The third time i contacted them looked like they felt pity for me and decided to acutally review the site themselves, but guess what:
"Also, I spent some more time reviewing your site and found a few links and docs which will help you in this scenario.
Why is My Site Not in the Index?
10 SEO Myths Reviewed
Is SEO The Future? No, And Here’s Why
Building Authority & Setting Expectations
The Role of Content Quality in Bing Ranking
"
What makes it more Irrational, is that the website actually was on bing and doing well, And is actually accepted in google AdSense, The website Is literally accepted by the most strict organization and bing yet doesn't index it. they decided one day just to block it or whatever they've done. They want me to go crazy searching for the non-existent problem. I feel Uncomfortable sharing the link here so imma just post the Results.
LightHouse Results: 99, 89, 93, 92, Core web vitals: failed (seems to me all websites fail this)

Ahrefs Score is 100

Site is indexed on google and yandex and has a daily 100 organic traffic.

Have you tried their webmaster tools https://www.bing.com/webmasters/ ?  Without seeing your site it is impossible to make suggestions. Lighthouse scores won't make/prevent something being indexed - misconfigured robots, cross-site duplicate content, low quality content etc. will.

Also a site "accepted in google AdSense," doesn't mean it's been listed in the organic Google results? Is it?

@RichardB It is on google organic results and it accumulates daily organic traffic, it was receiving 200-300 visitors a day in the last 4 years. but i abandoned  the website  2 years ago and came back recently, surprisingly while not caring about the website, it stayed on the top ranking. I still don't know why bing decided to cut it of.
"Lighthouse scores won't make/prevent something being indexed - misconfigured robots, cross-site duplicate content, low quality content etc. will." i don't think any of this is the case the website was up and running once in bing and is still on other SE
